# Position of buttons in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have searched for quite a bit and can't find an answer to my problem.

I have enabled the buttons panel in my jQuery DatePicker but am now wondering if it is possible to change the position of buttons? I need a "Today" and "Yesterday" button.

I have written the code for a custom button for "Yesterday" but is there a way to change the position of it?

What I need to do is have the buttons in the order of "Yesterday  Today  Done". Currently they are displayed as can be seen [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jrjt7t) here.

I have tried writing a code for a custom button for "Today" as well but it still doesn't position properly and on top of that, I can't seem to be able to find a way to hide the default buttons in the buttonPanel.

My code for the datepicker is as follows - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/509/):

```
var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        beforeShow: function (input) { 
            //dpClearButton(input);    
            dpMaxButton(input); 

        },
        showButtonPanel: true,
        beforeShow: function (input) { 
            //dpClearButton(input);    
            dpMaxButton(input); 

        },

        onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { 

            dpMaxButton(inst.input); 
        }
    };

    function dpMaxButton (input) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000*60*60*24);
            //alert (yesterday);
            var buttonPane = $(input)
            .datepicker("widget")
            .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            $("<button>", {
                text: "Yesterday",
                click: function () { 
                     jQuery(input).datepicker('setDate', yesterday);   
                     jQuery(input).datepicker('hide'); }
            }).appendTo(buttonPane).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
        }, 1)
    };

    date_input.datepicker(options);

    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
        $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
    };
```

Comment: can you create working code snippet?

Comment: @BhumiShah Added a JSFiddle to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/516/

First Added css

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current{
  float:none !important;
}
.pull-left{
  float:left !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function (input) { 
                //dpClearButton(input);    
                dpMaxButton(input); 

            },
      onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { 

                dpMaxButton(inst.input); 
            }
});
function dpMaxButton (input) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var d = new Date();
                var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000*60*60*24);
                //alert (yesterday);
                var buttonPane = $(input)
                .datepicker("widget")
                .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
                $("<button>", {
                    text: "Yesterday",
                    click: function () { 
                         jQuery(input).datepicker('setDate', yesterday);   
                         jQuery(input).datepicker('hide'); }
                }).appendTo(buttonPane).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all pull-left");
            }, 1)
        }
    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
            $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
        };
});
```